# php contact form only 'message' not coming through

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hi I have a contact form set up, initially it wasn't sending the file uploads which i managed to fix but now its not sending the 'message' from the form. name/email come through ok. please can you help, i'm sure this is the file with the error in?

```
<?PHP
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
/*
Interface to Captcha handler
*/
class FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    function Validate() { return false;}
    function GetError(){ return '';}
}
class FGContactForm
{
    var $receipients;
    var $errors;
    var $error_message;
    var $name;
    var $email;
    var $message;
    var $from_address;
    var $form_random_key;
    var $conditional_field;
    var $arr_conditional_receipients;
    var $fileupload_fields;
    var $captcha_handler;
    var $mailer;
    function FGContactForm()
    {
        $this->receipients = array();
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
        $this->conditional_field='';
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
        $this->fileupload_fields=array();
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    }
    function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
    {
        $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
        session_start();
    }
    function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
    {
        $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
    }
    function SetFromAddress($from)
    {
        $this->from_address = $from;
    }
    function SetFormRandomKey($key)
    {
        $this->form_random_key = $key;
    }
    function GetSpamTrapInputName()
    {
        return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->GetKey());
    }
    function SafeDisplay($value_name)
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
        {
            return'';
        }
        return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
    }
    function GetFormIDInputName()
    {
        $rand = md5('TygshRt'.$this->GetKey());
        $rand = substr($rand,0,20);
        return 'id'.$rand;
    }

    function GetFormIDInputValue()
    {
        return md5('jhgahTsajhg'.$this->GetKey());
    }
    function SetConditionalField($field)
    {
        $this->conditional_field = $field;
    }
    function AddConditionalReceipent($value,$email)
    {
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients[$value] =  $email;
    }
    function AddFileUploadField($file_field_name,$accepted_types,$max_size)
    {
            $this->fileupload_fields[] =
            array("name"=>$file_field_name,
            "file_types"=>$accepted_types,
            "maxsize"=>$max_size);
    }
    function ProcessForm()
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
        {
           return false;
        }
        if(!$this->Validate())
        {
            $this->error_message = implode('<br/>',$this->errors);
            return false;
        }
        $this->CollectData();
        $ret = $this->SendFormSubmission();
        return $ret;
    }
    function RedirectToURL($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }
    function GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $this->error_message;
    }
    function GetSelfScript()
    {
        return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
    function GetName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    function GetEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    function GetMessage()
    {
        return htmlentities($this->message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    }
/*--------  Private (Internal) Functions -------- */
    function SendFormSubmission()
    {
        $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();
        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact form submission from $this->name";
        $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();
        $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;
        $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);
        $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();
        $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
        $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
        $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);
        $this->AttachFiles();
        if(!$this->mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->add_error("Failed sending email!");
            return false;

          }
        return true;
    }
    function CollectConditionalReceipients()
    {
        if(count($this->arr_conditional_receipients)>0 &&
          !empty($this->conditional_field) &&
          !empty($_POST[$this->conditional_field]))
        {
            foreach($this->arr_conditional_receipients as $condn => $rec)
            {
                if(strcasecmp($condn,$_POST[$this->conditional_field])==0 &&
                !empty($rec))
                {
                    $this->AddRecipient($rec);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the relevant part on contact form

```
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='short_explanation'>*required fields</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
<label for='name' >Item 1 Details. Please include as much detail as possible, brand, colour, number condition, price*:</label><br/>
    <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="100" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
   </div>
```

so everything returns except 'message' assistance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML seems okay, have you checked the `CollectData()` method of your class to ensure `$_POST['message']` is being loaded into the class correctly (for example, `$this->message = $_POST['message']`)? Is the `ComposeFormtoEmail()` method reading `$this->message` correctly?

Comment: You need to look into how `msgHTML()` actually works; it sets `AltBody` for you, so will overwrite what you're putting in there beforehand, and it also has an injectable HTML to plain text conversion option which you could use instead of the external code you have.

Comment: Thank you both very much.....I've now managed to get it to work